# What are the important parameters for a standard diode equivalence?

Tags: diodes, schematics

I would like to know how could I replace an unavailable standard diode ([D7 ES3J](https://www.digikey.com.mx/es/products/detail/onsemi/ES3J/1087833)) which is used in this [schematic](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS/blob/master/Schematic_01.png) of a battery management system:

[image]

The main parameters of this diode are: Vrrm=600V; If(av)=3A; Ifsm=100A;
And the other product I am considering to be the one that replaced the diode mentioned before is the [S3J](https://www.mouser.mx/ProductDetail/onsemi-Fairchild/S3J?qs=a0wxjULRyoHC5P3OBZs10Q%3D%3D) and the main parameters are: Vrrm:600V; If(av)=3A; Ifsm=100A;

Are those parameters enough to replace the ES3J for the S3J diode?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, it _looks_ like it'll work -- but notice that I'm putting this into the comments and not making an answer of it.  To really _know_ you need to either try it and see if it blows up, or you need to have a competent circuit designer analyze the schematic and the proposed new part.  Note that if you're repairing something, parts don't just spontaneously blow up -- either something _else_ went wrong and took that diode out, or the original diode wasn't up to the task, and the new one may not be, either.

Comment: Thank you TimWescott! Your comment was helpful